# Изменение формы регистрации в redmine

Tags: регистрация, redmine

Есть ли возможность изменить форму регистрации в *redmine*, убрав из нее некоторые поля (например: Фамилия, Имя)?

Как добавить на форму регистрации ссылку на положение о конфиденциальности? В каком файле формируется код данной формы?

Может есть уже готовые решения, плагины и пр...

[image: Изменение формы регистрации в redmine]

Answer (score 1):

Остановился на следующем решении:

В файле **register.html.erb** (*./var/www/redmine-3.3.3/app/views/account/register.html.erb*) комментируем следующие строки:

```
<!--
<p><%= f.text_field :firstname, :required => true %></p>
<p><%= f.text_field :lastname, :required => true %></p>
-->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти изменения скроют поля Фамилия и Имя с формы регистрации

Кроме того необходимо убрать обязательность ввода этих поле. Для этого в файле **user.rb**(*./var/www/redmine-3.3.3/app/models/user.rb*) удаляем данные поля из строки

```
validates_presence_of :login, :firstname, :lastname, :if => Proc.new { |user| !user.is_a?(AnonymousUser) }
```

получив

```
validates_presence_of :login, :if => Proc.new { |user| !user.is_a?(AnonymousUser) }
```

После этого необходимо перезапустить redmine (у меня это выполняется командой "bundle exec thin restart -C /etc/thin/redmine.yml")